# text field with attached button

Tags: html, css, button, uitextfield

How do I get the textfield and button attached to each other

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/dgWqL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove the whitespace between `#textfield"` and `input[type="button"]`. 
(Whaaat?) Well, this is your html:

```
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="Search here" />
    <input name="" type="button" value="Go">
```

This is the same as having...

```
    abc
    def
```

...which, as you'd never question, gets rendered as `abc def`.

It's the exact same thing.

As I've suggested you can simple delete that whitespace by putting the second input right in front of the first one in the html, as so...

```
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="Search here" /><input name="" type="button" value="Go">
```

Another option is to comment out the whitespace - that's if you prefer to have each input on it's own line:

```
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="Search here" /><!--
  --><input name="" type="button" value="Go">
```

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dgWqL/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way : http://jsfiddle.net/dgWqL/2/
 The key is using *float*
**Suggestion:**

1. Do not use table for layout. *(It is bad practice.)*
2. Write your CSS properties on separate lines. *(Easier to read)* and make it easier to
   avoid repeatition like you did with `display: inline-block;`

Hope this help.